# Code Analysis recommends using const in definition but how in global.asax?

Tags: .net, security, optimization, constants, global-asax

Code

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    public const string globalServernameSHA = string.Empty;
    public static string globalSqlConnection = string.Empty;

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        globalServernameSHA = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["varServernameSHA"].ToString();
        globalSqlConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["varConnectionString"].ToString();
    }
```

These variables should be read just once and definitely should be read only. 
They have to be available for whole project and therefore should be public.

Is there a way how to define const in code like this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare them as readonly and move initialization to constructor:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    public readonly string globalServernameSHA;
    public readonly string globalSqlConnection;

    public Global()
    {
        globalServernameSHA = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["varServernameSHA"].ToString();
        globalSqlConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["varConnectionString"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: will this work with Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) ?

Comment: sure. but rememer, that constructor could be called multiple times, because asp.net maintains pool of application objects.

Answer (score 0):

They cannot be declared as `const` since the value is retrieved from the settings file. `const` values are always hard-coded into the executable program itself.

`readonly` is your best bet in the circumstance, which means the variables can only be set in the constructor (the instance or static constructor, depending on how you define the variables), or in a method called by the constructor when the variable is passed as a `ref`.

Comment: but the question is, can this be used from Application_start ?

Comment: @feronovak - Application_start is not the constructor, and it does not set a variable passed as ref. Therefore, readonly variables may be read from but not written to in Application_start